# WCF App_Code folder dosen't recognized

Tags: c#, wcf, data-access-layer

I have a WCF Service Application in C# with an App_Code folder in it.
The folder contains DAL.cs file with the same namespace as the Service1.svc and its public.
But when i try to use a function from the DAL class, the class isn't recognized.
What is that? and how can i fix it?

Comment: Is the calling code in the same project as DAL.cs? If not, you'll have to add a reference to the assembly containing DAL.cs.

Comment: I'm trying to call DAL.cs from the same project as the Service is.

Comment: Please show the DAL.cs class definition, and the calling code.

Comment: namespace LehavaWCF
{
    public class DAL
    {

Comment: public bool LoginCheck(string username,string password)
        {
            string sql="SELECT FROM Users Where username='"+username+"' AND password='"+password+"'";
            OleDbConnection con=DAL.getConnection();
            string ans = DAL.Exceute(con, sql);
            if (ans == "K")
                return true;
            return false;
        }

Comment: Please edit your post, and put the code there. That way you can format it and people can read it more easily. Code in comments is never a good idea unless it's a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the file property see if it's set to "Compile" instead of "Content"